# Android Saved uri giving null mediaPlayer object

Tags: android, uri, android-mediaplayer

I am creating this mediaPlayer object like         `mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(tone));`
Now the tone is the content uri as String of the file i want to play.Now it works well when I first select the tone from sdcard but if i save this uri in storage and then again execute this, it returns null even when both times the tone variable had the same value. Please help.

tone is content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A1350

Comment: Does the mediaPlayer simply becomes null or does it returns an error like MediaPlayer Error (-38,0) or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If moving a file from resources to a sd card or phone storage, the AndroidManifest.xml needs the following permission:

```
package="com.yourname.projectname">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<application
```

Comment: This permission was already there and I am able to get it right the first time but in subsequent attempts.